# TSQL Group By & Count not aggregating as expected

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, count, group-by

I have a query that returns 6 rows and I want to aggregate the information to provide a single row with a count of instances. The without aggregate query returns the correct data but when I add a GroupBy and Count to the query it returns 2 rows.

The underlying ID (SR01.ReportKey) shown in the first result has two records so I think the Group By is somehow using this field in the grouping.

NOTE: The ReportKey is not actually used in the query I just had it in the first result for information purposes.

*Question :*

Any idea why the Group By is not grouping all the rows into a single result with a count of 6?

**Without aggregate**

*Query :*

```
SELECT 
    'Open' AS RecStatus,
    ISNULL(UWZone.UWZoneID,'') AS ZoneID,
    ISNULL(UWZone.UWZoneName,'') AS ZoneName,
    Branch.BranchID,
    ISNULL(Branch.BranchName,'') AS BranchName,
    UW.UWID AS ServicingRep,
    ISNULL(UW.UWName,'') + '/' + ISNULL(UA.UWName, '') AS RepName
    FROM ProductivityRecommendations
        INNER JOIN SR01 ON SR01.ReportKey = ProductivityRecommendations.ReportKey
        LEFT JOIN UW ON SR01.Underwriter = UW.UWID
        LEFT JOIN UW AS UA ON SR01.UA = UA.UWID
        LEFT JOIN Branch ON SR01.ProdBranch = Branch.BranchID
        LEFT JOIN UWZone ON UWZone.UWZoneAbbrev = Branch.UWZone 
    WHERE ISNULL(SR01.ServicingBranch,'-') <> '-'
        AND ProductivityRecommendations.DateComplete BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo
        AND ProductivityRecommendations.RecCriticality IN ('CRI', 'CCM')
        AND ProductivityRecommendations.RecStatus IN ('N','O','U','A','R')
        AND DateRecIssued IS NOT NULL
        AND (@Zone IS NULL OR (UWZone.UWZoneID IN (SELECT val FROM ufn_SplitMax(@Zone ,','))))
        AND (@Branch IS NULL OR (Branch.BranchID IN (SELECT val FROM ufn_SplitMax(@Branch ,','))))
        AND (@RepID IS NULL OR (SR01.Underwriter IN(SELECT val FROM ufn_SplitMax(@RepID ,','))) OR @RepID IS NULL OR (SR01.UA IN(SELECT val FROM ufn_SplitMax(@RepID ,','))))
        AND (@InsuredNumber IS NULL OR (ProductivityRecommendations.CustNum IN (SELECT val FROM ufn_SplitMax(@InsuredNumber ,','))))
```

*Results :*

[image]

**Adding aggregates**

*Query :*

```
SELECT 
    'Open' AS RecStatus,
    ISNULL(UWZone.UWZoneID,'') AS ZoneID,
    ISNULL(UWZone.UWZoneName,'') AS ZoneName,
    Branch.BranchID,
    ISNULL(Branch.BranchName,'') AS BranchName,
    UW.UWID AS ServicingRep,
    ISNULL(UW.UWName,'') + '/' + ISNULL(UA.UWName, '') AS RepName,
    COUNT(ProductivityRecommendations.RecStatus) AS Requests
    FROM ProductivityRecommendations
        INNER JOIN SR01 ON SR01.ReportKey = ProductivityRecommendations.ReportKey
        LEFT JOIN UW ON SR01.Underwriter = UW.UWID
        LEFT JOIN UW AS UA ON SR01.UA = UA.UWID
        LEFT JOIN Branch ON SR01.ProdBranch = Branch.BranchID
        LEFT JOIN UWZone ON UWZone.UWZoneAbbrev = Branch.UWZone 
    WHERE ISNULL(SR01.ServicingBranch,'-') <> '-'
        AND ProductivityRecommendations.DateComplete BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo
        AND ProductivityRecommendations.RecCriticality IN ('CRI', 'CCM')
        AND ProductivityRecommendations.RecStatus IN ('N','O','U','A','R')
        AND DateRecIssued IS NOT NULL
        AND (@Zone IS NULL OR (UWZone.UWZoneID IN (SELECT val FROM ufn_SplitMax(@Zone ,','))))
        AND (@Branch IS NULL OR (Branch.BranchID IN (SELECT val FROM ufn_SplitMax(@Branch ,','))))
        AND (@RepID IS NULL OR (SR01.Underwriter IN(SELECT val FROM ufn_SplitMax(@RepID ,','))) OR @RepID IS NULL OR (SR01.UA IN(SELECT val FROM ufn_SplitMax(@RepID ,','))))
        AND (@InsuredNumber IS NULL OR (ProductivityRecommendations.CustNum IN (SELECT val FROM ufn_SplitMax(@InsuredNumber ,','))))
    GROUP BY UWZone.UWZoneID, UWZone.UWZoneName, Branch.BranchID, Branch.BranchName, SR01.ServicingRep, UW.UWID, ISNULL(UW.UWName,'') + '/' + ISNULL(UA.UWName, '')
```

*Results :*

[image]

Comment: Probably one of the columns you `GROUP BY` has the values of `''` and `NULL`. So if you `GROUP BY ISNULL(UWZone.UWZoneID,'') ...` it would hopefully work.

Comment: Just wrapped all the fields with ISNULLs and the results are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @Johan said in a comment:

This will should give you 1 row only in your described senario:

```
GROUP BY 
  ISNULL(UWZone.UWZoneID,''),
  ISNULL(UWZone.UWZoneName,''),
  Branch.BranchID,
  ISNULL(Branch.BranchName,'') ,
  UW.UWID,
  ISNULL(UW.UWName,''),
  ISNULL(UA.UWName, '')
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, the underlying issue was grouping by the 2 UWName fields separately rather than concatenated together.

Answer (score 0):

Try a "select distinct" of the columns that you are grouping by, and also a LEN to see if they have spaces or other char that are not seen, and also test for NULLs. Then, you decide how to handel these columns, using ISNULL, COALESCE, CASE, and/or WHERE statements, depending on what you need.